# What background is needed to study quantum game theory?

Tags: soft-question, computational-complexity, game-theory

Currently I am learning ( a beginner ) about Bell inequalities and device independent outlook on quantum mechanics. I come across some papers using these concept in quantum game theory. Most of the papers I just browsed through to find make use of linear programming a lot. Some make use of complexity classes also. To learn about quantum game theory what basics precisely one needs ? I had taken up courses way long back about complexity classes and linear programming. Do I need to learn them again properly and what else background is needed ?

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing a good answer to this question also -- thanks for asking it.

Comment: I would assume that topic like this needs strong knowledge of probability theory.

Comment: Thank you for asking the question. I need this answered as well...

Comment: @Kugelblitz But I don't think I would be getting an answer, will try with a higher bounty .

Comment: @sasha Give it a while; I'll put up a +100 Bounty on your question after this one ends. We might have to add more context to the question though...

Comment: Meanwhile, I found this: http://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0506219v1.pdf

It's amazing. As a 11th grader, I'll take a while getting through this; I'm sure it will be of some use to you as well as @Shane.

Comment: More resources in this link: http://web.mit.edu/redingtn/www/netadv/Xgame.html

I'll be using them after finishing that introductory pdf.
Cheers.

Comment: @Kugelblitz Indeed. Very nice. Thanks for sharing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another place to start:
http://www.thebigquestions.com/eorms.pdf
Obviously, you should learn some basic game theory first, to understand the concepts before adding in quantum. I like Matthew Jackson's
http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1968579.  Hope this helps.
Trurl.